# THE sigma-ring or A sigma-ring?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have two questions about sigma-rings and measure spaces.

Let $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mu)$ be any measure space. Is $\mathscr{F}$ THE sigma-ring of this space or A sigma-ring of this space? If instead we are given a measurable space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F})$, then is $\mathscr{F}$ THE sigma-ring or A sigma-ring?

Though simple, short, and heuristic comments are welcome, I am looking for a proof.

Comment: $\mathcal F$ is *the* sigma-ring of the spaces $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mu)$ and $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$. Secondly it is *a* sigma-ring on set $\Omega$. A proof? For the fact that your head is the head of your body?

Comment: @drhab: Thank you for your comment; I assume you did not want to talk in this way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several $\sigma$-rings on the *set* $\Omega$ can be build. But the mesurable *space* $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ is a pair and $\mathcal{F}$ is the $\sigma$-ring of this space.

Comment: Thanks very much. But, as it seems to me, the post contains some assertions and no more? You might just want to say more?